# Odoo website modal open when click on card item

Tags: odoo, modal-dialog, popup, odoo-16

I have created a custom static snippet for card item. the card items title, text and image can be editable staticly. I want to modify the card item, when click on the card a popup/modal will be show and display the specific card items content. and also the pop up will be editable staticaly

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<odoo>
    <template id="s_case_study" name="Case Study">
        <section class="s_case_study border-none modal-false py-5">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="text-center pb-5">
                    <h3 class="">Our Case Study Area</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col p-3">
                        <div class="card h-100"
                             data-bs-toggle="modal"
                             data-bs-target="#exampleModalCenter">
                            <div class="card-image">
                                <img class="object-fit" src="/theme_tvs/static/src/img/s_case_study_card_image.png" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="card-title px-3 pt-3">
                                <h5>Card Title</h5>
                            </div>
                            <div class="card-text px-3">
                                <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col p-3">
                        <div class="card h-100"
                        data-bs-toggle="modal"
                        data-bs-target="#exampleModalCenter">
                            <div class="card-image">
                                <img class="object-fit" src="/theme_tvs/static/src/img/s_case_study_card_image.png" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="card-title px-3 pt-3">
                                <h5>Card Title</h5>
                            </div>
                            <div class="card-text px-3">
                                <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col p-3">
                        <div class="card h-100">
                            <div class="card-image">
                                <img class="object-fit" src="/theme_tvs/static/src/img/s_case_study_card_image.png" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="card-title px-3 pt-3">
                                <h5>Card Title</h5>
                            </div>
                            <div class="card-text px-3">
                                <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col p-3">
                        <div class="card h-100">
                            <div class="card-image">
                                <img class="object-fit" src="/theme_tvs/static/src/img/s_case_study_card_image.png" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="card-title px-3 pt-3">
                                <h5>Card Title</h5>
                            </div>
                            <div class="card-text px-3">
                                <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <!-- Modal -->
                    <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalCenter" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
                      <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
                        <div class="modal-content">
                          <div class="modal-header">
                              <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">Modal Title</h5>
                              <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
                          </div>
                          <div class="modal-body">
                              Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
                          </div>
                          <div class="modal-footer">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save Changes</button>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
    </template>
</odoo>
```

[image: Output result]

> I want that, Every card item have separate dynamic modal/popup. and also all the popups will be editabel (like, first card popup title will be "Hello World" and 2nd card popup title will be "Messi is best" and 3rd, 4th title will be randomly editable)

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: read the last two lines. there I said, I want a popup/modal which will be apear when I click on the card item

Comment: sorry Shatu, but that's not even a question. please also add more information like your codes, what have you tried so far, and your results. this is a minimum concise requirement for a reasonable question in here.